# In Unity, How do I create a AnimationClip that exists in the project?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Here's what I want to do:

I want to programmatically, in the code, change a value or values of an existing AnimationClip. I have been unable to find a simple clear answer of how to do so.

What I need to know:

1) Instantiate, in code, an existing AnimationClip, located in a folder of the unity project.

2)Access and change values of a keyframe of the animation (say, at keyframe 100 I want to change the rotation.z value of the animation).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to change the values of the keyframe? Which effect is it you wish to achieve? Perhaps there is a better way.

Comment: The effect is to change the animation to have a "target", i.e. do a spinning motion to face the enemy and then animate movement towards this enemy.